# sql multiple updates in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

What is the best way to handle return values when using multiple update statements in a stored procedure.

I am using this stored procedure in a data adapter and am trying to get the update result total.

I'm using **SQL Server 2008** and .NET 4.5

For example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usrsp_MessageConversation_delete]
(
    @fromMbrID int,
    @toMbrID int
)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT OFF;
UPDATE mbr_Messages
SET  fromDeleted = 1
WHERE (fromMbrID = @fromMbrID) AND (toMbrID = @toMbrID)

UPDATE mbr_Messages
    SET toDeleted = 1
WHERE (fromMbrID = @toMbrID) AND (toMbrID = @fromMbrID)

//RETURN TOTAL NUMBER OF UPDATED RECORDS
    EG: RETURN  @@ROWCOUNT ??

END
```

I want to return the total number of updated records or 0 if non were updated.

Do I need to add any other error handling - if so any suggestions?

**UPDATE: I ended up going with this:**

```
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @rowCounter INT;

BEGIN TRY 

    UPDATE 
        mbr_Messages
    SET 
        fromDeleted = 1
    WHERE 
        (fromMbrID = @fromMbrID) AND (toMbrID = @toMbrID) AND (fromDeleted = 0);

    SET @rowCounter = @@ROWCOUNT;

    UPDATE 
        mbr_Messages
    SET 
        toDeleted = 1
    WHERE 
        (fromMbrID = @toMbrID) AND (toMbrID = @fromMbrID) AND (toDeleted = 0);

    SET @rowCounter = @rowCounter + @@ROWCOUNT;

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT 'Update failed';
END CATCH 

RETURN @rowCounter

END
```

Comment: You should execute those queries as a transaction, so that you can rollback if one of them fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to do something like below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usrsp_MessageConversation_delete]
(
    @fromMbrID int,
    @toMbrID int
)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT OFF;
    DECLARE @RowCount1 INTEGER
    DECLARE @RowCount2 INTEGER
    DECLARE @TotalRows INTEGER

UPDATE mbr_Messages
SET  fromDeleted = 1
WHERE (fromMbrID = @fromMbrID) AND (toMbrID = @toMbrID)

SET @RowCount1=@@RowCount

UPDATE mbr_Messages
    SET toDeleted = 1
WHERE (fromMbrID = @toMbrID) AND (toMbrID = @fromMbrID)

SET @RowCount2=@@RowCount

SET @TotalRows = @RowCount1 + @RowCount2

--RETURN TOTAL NUMBER OF UPDATED RECORDS
  RETURN  @TotalRows

END
```

You need to assign @@RowCount to some variable as it gets reset once you use it.

**Edit:**

Also add error handling code: Try..Catch and Transactions.

Comment: thanks, the rowcounter being overwritten after each execution was the problem

Answer (score 1):

If your stored procedure is short, I not really suggest to use any error handling.

But here is one example for error handling

```
IF @@ERROR <> 0 
BEGIN
   --your statement 
   return 12345; -- to mark your error location 
END
```

More information about [@@Error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188790%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Use a transaction,  near the start of your procedure use this command to start a transaction:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
```

Check for errors in your script (can be used multiple times)

```
IF @@ERROR <> 0
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK
    RAISERROR ('error updating something', 16,1)
    RETURN
END
```

then at the end of your script commit the transaction

```
COMMIT
```

Comment: thanks but thats only part of the answer - i am wanting to know the best way to get the return value of the total number of rows updated back out into the data adapter

Answer (score 0):

you can use [OUTPUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms177564.aspx) clause to count updated/inserted or deleted records

```
DECLARE @MyTableVar table (
flagdeleted bit NOT NULL);

UPDATE mbr_Messages
SET fromDeleted = 1
OUTPUT INSERTED.fromDeleted INTO @MyTableVar 
WHERE (fromMbrID = @fromMbrID) AND (toMbrID = @toMbrID)

UPDATE mbr_Messages
SET toDeleted = 1
OUTPUT INSERTED.toDeleted INTO @MyTableVar 
WHERE (fromMbrID = @toMbrID) AND (toMbrID = @fromMbrID)

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @MyTableVar //here is the number of updated records
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usrsp_MessageConversation_delete]
(
    @fromMbrID int,
    @toMbrID int
)
AS
DECLARE 
@SQL1 VARCHAR(800),
@SQL2 VARCHAR(800)
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT OFF;

SET @SQL1 ='
UPDATE mbr_Messages
SET  fromDeleted = ''1''
WHERE (fromMbrID = '+@fromMbrID+') AND (toMbrID = '+@toMbrID+')'
PRINT @SQL1

SET @SQL2 ='
UPDATE mbr_Messages
    SET toDeleted = ''1''
WHERE (fromMbrID = '+@toMbrID+') AND (toMbrID = '+@fromMbrID+')'

PRINT @sql2


EXEC(@SQL1)

EXEC(@SQL2)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRAN
 -- Your code here
COMMIT TRAN
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRAN
END CATCH
```

This will return number of rows affected (updated row). 0 (affected row will be 0 after roll back) if error.

Answer (score 0):

The return value for `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery` will give you the number of rows affected by your query. In your case it will add the row counts of the two `UPDATE` statements in your proc. There is no need to add a RETURN statement to your stored procedure.

```
SqlCommand command;
...
int numberOfRecords = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```